# Wordpress: show category-page as frontpage

Tags: wordpress

I want to show a category-page on the frontpage without the url changing (eg. redirect).
The frontpage should implement the categories' head and meta tags then and also the top menu should display the appropriate category selected. also there should be a canonical tag to the categorypage so no duplicate content will be generated.

short: the frontpage should exactly behave like a categorypage.

is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own page template and set is as start page.
Go to:
Apperance->Customize

Then Static front page.
Choose "Static Page"

Then choose your page from the dropdown list.

If you need help look at this.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tan's answer, you'll need to go to Settings -> Reading and then select 'A static page' for the 'Front page displays' option. After that you can select your previously created page template from the 'A static page' drop-down menu.

When you finish the above, you'll have to edit the source code for the chosen file in order to include a standard wp loop. For more info, please check this thread:
[How do I make a Wordpress Page act like the default home page displaying multiple posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001872/how-do-i-make-a-wordpress-page-act-like-the-default-home-page-displaying-multipl)

To control which posts will be shown in the loop use the `query_posts()`. You can find more details here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts